# WPF overload custom binding constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my code:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding {

    public MyBinding(string path, bool value) : base(path) { /*...*/ }

    public MyBinding(string path, int value) : base(path) { /*...*/ }

}
```

I can do this:

```
<Control Property="{MyBinding Variable, True}" />
```

But can't do this:

```
<Control Property="{MyBinding Variable, 123}" />
```

It seems like only the first constructor is taken into account. Why?

Comment: If you remove the working constructor, will the other one be valid by the compiler?

Comment: Yes. It works normally.

Comment: `123` is just a string in XAML.

Comment: Not if you type the argument, my application reads it as Int32

Comment: https://imgur.com/ZPZmQSy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XAML processor tries to invoke the *first* constructor it finds. If works if you change the order of the constuctors or if you remove the first one:

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    public MyBinding(string path, int value) : base(path) { } //primary
    public MyBinding(string path, bool value) : base(path) { } //secondary
}
```

In XAML values such as 'True' and '123' are nothing but `strings`. The conversion to a `bool` or `int` is performed by the parser at runtime.

XAML is not a strongly-type programming language. It's a XML (text) based markup language.

The tooltip in Visual Studio will display `Int32` even if you type:

```
{MyBinding Variable, xyz}
```

That doesn't mean that converting xyz to a `System.Int32` will succeed at runtime. It obviously won't.

Comment: To anyone reading this, please note that overloading by the number of parameters still works. Only type overloading is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get overloading working on the constructor, but you can add typed properties.

```
public class MyBinding : Binding
{
    public MyBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
    }

    private int _intvalue = 0;
    public int IntValue { get => _intvalue; set { _intvalue = value; } }

    private string _stringvalue = null;
    public string StringValue { get => _stringvalue; set { _stringvalue = value; } }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <Label Content="{local:MyBinding SomeProperty, IntValue=123}" />
    <Label Content="{local:MyBinding SomeProperty, StringValue=123}" />
```

---

I would not choose this solution, but it's an option:

```
public MyBinding(string path, string param) : base(path)
{
    int x;
    double d;
    bool b;
    if (Int32.TryParse(param, out x))
    {
        //  ...
    }
    else if (Double.TryParse(param, out d))
    {
        //  ...
    }
    else if (Boolean.TryParse(param, out b))
    {
        //  ...
    }
}
```