# WPF nested property binding not working if parent property is null

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following situtation:

```
<DatePicker IsEnabled="{Binding ParentObject.EditAvailable}"
```

Now if I set `ParentObject`to `null`in my ViewModel which is also the `DataContext` the `IsEnabled` Property on the `DatePicker` will be set to `true`

The binding is working completely correct for all instances if the `ParentObject` is properly set.

But I don't really get that behavior in WPF.

A workaround would be using:

```
<DatePicker IsEnabled="{Binding ParentObject.EditAvailable, FallbackValue=False}"
```

So now if the `ParentObject` is set to `null` via my ViewModel, the `IsEnabled` property on the `DatePicker` returns `false`.

Is there anything I can do without setting the `FallbackValue` on each of my controls in my project?
It's already huge and I need to find a solution to have it somehow as default behavior that if the `ParentObject` is null, that there is a default value set default(bool), default(string) etc etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: could you show the definition of  ParentObject?

Comment: @Frenchy ParentObject is a "POCO" implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. So nothing special to see there.

Comment: Could you set IsEnabled for the whole window, rather than each individual control?

Comment: @Robin not on the whole window, but setting in on some sort of container containing my controls would also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `IsEnabled` on the panel or grid that contains the controls, and it will affect all controls it contains.

```
<StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding ParentObject.EditAvailable, FallbackValue=False}">
    <DatePicker />
    <DatePicker />
    <DatePicker />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do without setting the FallbackValue on each of my controls in my project?

No, not apart from replacing each binding with a custom one that sets the `FallbackValue` by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684132/wpf-overload-custom-binding-constructor/47698456#47698456) for an example.

You will still have to replace `{Binding` with `{local:YourBinding` everywhere.

Comment: And how would I achieve my custom binding to return the default value of a simple type?

Comment: @Luca: I am afraid there is no easy way to do this since you don't know the value or type of the property that you bind to.

Answer (score 1):

If binding Path is always the same, then you can use default style for DatePicker:

```
<Style TargetType="DatePicker">
  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding ParentObject.EditAvailable, FallbackValue=False}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is totally fine, but unfortunatly that's not the case. 
The binding path can be anything, it's just simplified for asking the question